# How can I find the host for a website I own but didn't set up?

Tags: web-hosting

I was recently appointed as the "computer guy" for the church I attend. My predecessor died of old age. She had lived on her own, and wasn't on speaking terms with her family. One of my first tasks in my new post was to hack into her laptop; I managed to extract the files she'd saved locally, but it seemed that she'd saved all the useful stuff to her Google Drive, which is beyond my abilities to hack.

The same lady also set up the church's website. It's a horrible mess, and, worse than that, I can't see anything within its pages which indicates where it's hosted, or by whom.

I want to fix my church's website. Any ideas for finding who is hosting it? If I can't find that out, given that I - by which I mean the parish - own the domain, can I force the URL to point to another server?

Comment: The website: `http://www.maltbystmm.org/`

Comment: When you say that the church owns the domain name does that mean that somebody actually has access to the registry account where the domain name was bought? Or is somebody's contact information from the church listed in the who is for the domain?

Comment: Perhaps you can ask the church financial person who is paying for the website hosting. Maybe the bills will divulge more info, including contact info you can call for help about your situation, including taking over the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your website hostname, through a CNAME resolves to this IP address:

```
$ dig www.maltbystmm.org +short
maltbystmm.org.
198.71.232.4
```

This IP address is owned by GoDaddy, from a whois output:

```
NetRange:       198.71.128.0 - 198.71.255.255
CIDR:           198.71.128.0/17
NetName:        GO-DADDY-COM-LLC
NetHandle:      NET-198-71-128-0-1
Parent:         NET198 (NET-198-0-0-0-0)
```

There is no HTTP redirection when trying to connect to it, so your webhosting company is GoDaddy.

You can also find that by looking at the image at bottom, saying "Powered by Website Builder" and if you click on that link, you get various informations and plans to pay for this website (and `secureserver.net` in URL means GoDaddy).

Comment: Can you add instructions for changing where this domain points in DNS?